# Getting error when inserting into temptable

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a #temptable which I'm trying to populate but its not working.

```
DECLARE
         @nBranchId int 
        ,@tmStartDate datetime
        ,@tmEndDate datetime 


SELECT   @nBranchId = 3483
        ,@tmStartDate = DATEADD(DAY, -10, GETDATE())
        ,@tmEndDate = GETDATE()


CREATE table #temptable (
     nResultsId int
    ,nInstrId int
    ,nBranchId int
    ,nFoldersId int
    ,strPaperId varchar(50)
    ,strPosName varchar(50)
    ,fQuantity float
    ,fRevaluationPrice float
    ,fHistRevaluationPrice float
    ,tmDate datetime
    ,nPrevResultsId int
) 

INSERT INTO #temptable
SELECT  
         xpr.nResultsId
        ,xpr.nInstrId
        ,xpr.nBranchId
        ,xpr.nFoldersId
        ,xpr.strPaperId
        ,xpr.strPosName
        ,xpr.fQuantity
        ,xpr.fRevaluationPrice
        ,xpr.fHistRevaluationPrice
        ,xpr.tmDate
        ,nPrevResultsId = dbo.fnGetPrevTradeResultId(xpr.nBranchId, xpr.nInstrId, xpr.strPaperId, xpr.strPosName,xpr.tmDate, xpr.nFoldersId) 
FROM    dbo.XP_Results AS xpr WITH(READUNCOMMITTED)
WHERE 1 = 1
        AND xpr.nBranchId = ISNULL(@nBranchId, xpr.nBranchId)
        AND xpr.tmDate BETWEEN @tmStartDate AND @tmEndDate
        AND xpr.nInstrId <> 18


DROP table #temptable
```

Getting this error:

Msg 8152, Level 16, State 14, Line 28
String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.

Where am I missing it? Have looked and looked but can't solve it

Comment: Can you post the definition of `dbo.XP_Results`?

Comment: Sounds like you'll want to look at the lengths of the XP_Results varchar columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have different length data types

To avoid this problem use a [`SELECT INTO`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select_into.asp) statement

`#Temptable` would be created automatically with correct data type (Extra benefit you don't have to script `CREATE` statement)

```
DECLARE
         @nBranchId int 
        ,@tmStartDate datetime
        ,@tmEndDate datetime 


SELECT   @nBranchId = 3483
        ,@tmStartDate = DATEADD(DAY, -10, GETDATE())
        ,@tmEndDate = GETDATE()

SELECT   xpr.nResultsId
        ,xpr.nInstrId
        ,xpr.nBranchId
        ,xpr.nFoldersId
        ,xpr.strPaperId
        ,xpr.strPosName
        ,xpr.fQuantity
        ,xpr.fRevaluationPrice
        ,xpr.fHistRevaluationPrice
        ,xpr.tmDate
        ,nPrevResultsId = dbo.fnGetPrevTradeResultId(xpr.nBranchId, xpr.nInstrId, xpr.strPaperId, xpr.strPosName,xpr.tmDate, xpr.nFoldersId) 
INTO #temptable
FROM    dbo.XP_Results AS xpr WITH(READUNCOMMITTED)
WHERE 1 = 1
        AND xpr.nBranchId = ISNULL(@nBranchId, xpr.nBranchId)
        AND xpr.tmDate BETWEEN @tmStartDate AND @tmEndDate
        AND xpr.nInstrId <> 18


DROP table #temptable
```

Answer (score 1):

Should be fixed by changing these two columns to look like this. Likely what is going on is, you are trying to insert varchars greater than 50 characters into a varchar(50) column.

```
strPaperId varchar(max),
strPosName varchar(max)
```

Comment: Thank you. Didn't see that coming

Answer (score 1):

That means that one of your columns has data that is larger than the data type size you declared for the temp table column.

For example, if you have a temp table column of `varchar(2)`, then try to insert the value '123', you would get that error message because the value we are inserting is longer than the size of the column you are inserting into.  Note that this message can mean any type.

Find the temp table column with the problem and increase the size to the size in the actual table.